# How to get an instagram feed on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, instagram

I am trying to get instafeed to work on galnova.com but nothing is happening

galnova.com

this is the code that they told me to insert on the site but I have no control over it.

http://galnova.com/2015/js/instafeed.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: '',
        clientId: ' MYCLIENTID',
        useHTTP: true
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Then on the page I am using this

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

and nothing is populating. It's telling me

Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid

I'm using the actual token I got from the instagram page and it's not working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iframe` or somehow plugin like http://instafeedjs.com

[Example](http://kozikcocoon.com)

Comment: I edited my question and page and still nothing is loading. Would you happen to have any idea why this is not loading?